# Rails: Query with inner join, ordering by association and no duplicate records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So I'm trying to create the ability to search appointments in my app and am having trouble with duplicate records and ordering.

To summarize:

An appointment is between two users with one being the `booker` and one being the `bookee` being booked. An appointment also `has_many :time_options` that a user can suggest, and then when the `bookee` selects and confirms one of these suggested `time_options` the `start_time` is applied to the similar `start_time` attribute on appointments. The models are structured as follows:

```rb
#appointment.rb
belongs_to :booker, foreign_key: :booker_id, 
                                class_name: 'Profile'
belongs_to :bookee, foreign_key: :bookee_id, 
                                class_name: 'Profile'
has_many :time_options, dependent: :destroy

scope :order_by_start_time, -> {
               joins(:time_options)
               .order("COALESCE(appointments.start_time, time_options.start_time) DESC")
              }

def self.search(search)
  if search
    search_term = "%#{search}%"
    joins(
          "INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.id IN (appointments.booker_id, 
                                                  appointments.bookee_id)"
         )
    .where(
           "CONCAT_WS(' ', profiles.first_name, profiles.last_name) ILIKE :term 
            OR appointments.service_title ILIKE :term", 
            term: search_term
           )
  else
    where(nil)
  end
end
```

```
#time_option.rb 
 belongs_to :appointment, touch: true
 belongs_to :profile
```

```rb
#profile.rb
 belongs_to :user, touch: true
 has_many :booker_appointments, foreign_key: :booker_id,
                                class_name: 'Appointment', 
                                dependent: :nullify
 has_many :bookee_appointments, foreign_key: :bookee_id, 
                                class_name: 'Appointment', 
                                dependent: :nullify
```

I'm trying to let users search appointments by their appointment's `service_title`, or the other user's name (whether they are the `booker` or the `bookee`). I then want to order those search results by `start_time`. Either the `start_time` of the Appointment itself (which is only set when an appointment is confirmed), or if the appointment hasn't been confirmed yet and it's `start_time` is `nil`, then to instead use the earliest `start_time` of the associated `time_options`.

So in the controller, I'm doing something like:

```rb
  def index
    @appointments = Appointment.all_profile_appointments(@profile)
    if params[:search]
      @upcoming_appointments = @appointments.search(params[:search])                             
                                            .order_by_start_time
                                            .page(params[:page])
                                            .per(12)
    else
      @upcoming_appointments = @appointments.order_by_start_time
                                            .page(params[:page])
                                            .per(12)
      end
    end
```

However, my search method returns duplicates, I believe because of the `INNER JOIN`. And if I add `.distinct` before or after the `order_by_start_time method`, I get the wonderful error: `PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

So I'm pretty sure I just need to write a more complex, precise SQL statement; but, between needing to join the `profiles` table to search by name, needing join/coalesce the `time_options` table to order by `start_time` I'm not quite sure where to go next. For background, I'm using `postgresql` and Rails 4.

TL;DR: I'm trying to search for Appointment records by the name of the Profile who either booked or was booked, for the appointment. I'm then looking to order that query by `appointments.start_time`, or if no appointment start_time has been confirmed, then by the earliest `time_options.start_time` associated with the appointment. And I'm trying to do this without a pile of duplicate records.

Comment: This is a pretty tough read, could you please consider splitting this code into decent length lines?

Comment: @max Sorry about that, I tried to make it better. Is it still unclear?

Comment: Much better. I think you might want to try doing the join in a subquery.